# Using implicit function theorem in case of square matrices

Tags: real-analysis

Let $p_1,p_2 \in \mathbb{N}-\{0\}.$ I need to use the implicit function theorem to show that there exists an open neighborhood $U \in \mathbb{R}^{n,n}$ of the unit matrix $I_n \in \mathbb{R}^{n,n}$ such that for all $x \in U$ there exists $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n,n}$ with $x^{p_1}=y^{p_2}.$

Even though I understand the implicit function theorem, I do not see how to use it in this setting. Can somebody provide some insight or a solution proposal ? Thanks.

Comment: I would try the function $f(x,y) = x^{p_{1}} - y^{p_{2}}$. Show that $f(I,I) = 0$ and the derivative of $f$ is surjective.